# Prove that $G$ has a cycle of length $\leq4$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be an undirected simple graph with $n\leq9$ vertices and each vertex has $m\geq3$ neighbours. Show that $G$ has a cycle of length $\leq4$.

My first idea was to just assume that $G$ has exactly $9$ vertices and each vertex has exactly $3$ neighbours. If the statement is true for $n=9$, then it must be true for $n<9$, too, same thing for $m>3$. How can I now show mathematically, that $G$ with $n=9$ and $m=3$ actually contains a cycle of length $\leq4$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is false if we allow graphs with $n=0$ vertices.
So to proof the claim, we may assume $n\ge1$, each vertex has degree $\ge 3$, all cycles have length $\ge 5$, and from this we try to show that $n>9$.

Pick a vertex $v$, and from its at least three neighbours pick $w_1,w_2,w_3$. For each $w_i$, pick two neighbours $u_{i,1}, u_{i,2}$ distinct from $v$.
Note that $u_{i,j}\ne w_k$ as otherwise we'd have a cycle of length $3$.
Also, $u_{i,j}\ne u_{i',j'}$ for $(i',j')\ne(i,j)$ because otherwise, we'd have a cycle of length $4$. 
Thus the ten vertices 
$$ v,w_1,w_2,w_3,u_{1,1},u_{1,2},u_{2,1},u_{2,2},u_{3,1},u_{3,2}$$
are pairwise distinct, and so $n\ge10$.

Comment: Quick question: We now know, that we need (atleast) 10 vertices to have no cycles of length less than 5, but does this already fully prove the statement? We now know that we will get a cycle of length 4 with n=9. What about the cycle of length 3?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. We could just now say that with 9 vertices we need to have an edge from a $w_k$ to another $w_k$, so there is a cycle of length 3. Alright, thanks!

Comment: Nevermind again: We just have to show that a cycle of length $\leq4$ exists, so a cycle of length 4 is already enough.